# freebsd missing mysql option at drupal install

Tags: mysql, sqlite, drupal-7, freebsd

I have phpmyadmin installed which works fine with a mysql database.
But when installing drupal i only have the option to select a SQLite database type.

I've downloaded the latest drupal (7.9)

maybe it is a permission thing? But I don't know where to look and set permissions. But it could be somthing else though...

When i try `php -m | grep mysql` i get:

```
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
```

This means that php is working with mysql if I'm correct.

So my question is how do i get the mysql(i) available to my drupal install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install pdo_mysql from port 
**/usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql**

```
sudo portinstall -v databases/php5-pdo_mysql
```

or

```
cd /usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql && sudo make all install clean
```

In general I recommend you to update ports tree and install last drupal from port **/usr/ports/www/drupal7**, and this procedure installs all required dependencies:

```
sudo portinstall -v www/drupal7
```

or

```
cd /usr/ports/www/drupal7 && sudo make all install clean
```

Comment: thnx i found this solution elsewhere but did not know about the drupal port :) thnx for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to instal Drupal from FreeBSD' ports tree (/usr/ports/www/drupal7).